# How can I name an aggregate column in spark scala sql instead of default given one?

Tags: sql, scala, apache-spark, apache-spark-sql

In my homework I must create a cube out of two tables. Everything gets fine using scala, expect from the part where I create an aggregation using the following query :

```
val borrowersAggregation = spark.sql("""SELECT borrowersTable.gender,borrowersTable.department,COUNT(loansTable.bid) FROM borrowersTable,loansTable WHERE borrowersTable.bid = loansTable.bid GROUP BY borrowersTable.gender,borrowersTable.department WITH CUBE""")
    borrowersAggregation.show();
    
    borrowersAggregation.createOrReplaceTempView("cube")
```

The new column is named count(bid) but I want a different name. Can I somehow rename it inside the body of the query or should I write down an extra line of code ?
Thanks !

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You can put column aliases using `AS`

```
spark.sql("""
SELECT
    borrowersTable.gender,
    borrowersTable.department,
    COUNT(loansTable.bid) AS count_bid
FROM borrowersTable,loansTable
WHERE borrowersTable.bid = loansTable.bid
GROUP BY borrowersTable.gender,borrowersTable.department WITH CUBE
""")
```

Answer (score 2):

you can alias the column using `as <new_column_name>`

```
val borrowersAggregation = spark.sql("""SELECT borrowersTable.gender,borrowersTable.department,COUNT(loansTable.bid) as <new_column_name> FROM borrowersTable,loansTable WHERE borrowersTable.bid = loansTable.bid GROUP BY borrowersTable.gender,borrowersTable.department WITH CUBE""")
```

alternatively using **`dataframe`** functions using `.withColumn()` or `.withColumnRenamed()`

```
val borrowersAggregation = spark.sql("""SELECT borrowersTable.gender,borrowersTable.department,COUNT(loansTable.bid)  FROM borrowersTable,loansTable WHERE borrowersTable.bid = loansTable.bid GROUP BY borrowersTable.gender,borrowersTable.department WITH CUBE""").withColumnRenamed("count(*)","<new_column_name>")

//or using withColumn function
val borrowersAggregation = spark.sql("""SELECT borrowersTable.gender,borrowersTable.department,COUNT(loansTable.bid)  FROM borrowersTable,loansTable WHERE borrowersTable.bid = loansTable.bid GROUP BY borrowersTable.gender,borrowersTable.department WITH CUBE""").withColumn("<new_column_name>","count(*)").drop("count(*)")
```